# Python Class recurrence

Tags: python, class, super

I don't understand why my code works. I don't have practical application for this code; just wondering about classes in python.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(20)

class A():
    def __init__(self):
    self.a = object

    def rec(self,argument):
        self.a = argument

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B,self).__init__()
        self.a = self

myObject = B()
myObject.rec(myObject)


print(myObject.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a)
```

Recurrsion limit should forbid me from printing last line. But i can call an attribute like forever.

Comment: Where's the recursion?

Comment: Why would the recursion limit forbid that last line? It's not recursive and wouldn't be near the limit if it was.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't recursion in a way that would eat up the call stack, which is what [`sys.setrecursionlimit` deals with](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit):

> Set the maximum depth of the Python interpreter stack to limit. . .

This is just self-referencing the same object over and over again, which doesn't consume memory or stack frames like a recursive function call would.

Think of this as a linked list, but where each Node just points at itself instead of another Node. It will only consume enough memory for the self-referencing Node, and unless you try to iterate it recursively, doesn't involve any recursive function calls.

This is an (arguably) recursive structure, not a set of recursive function calls.

Answer (score 2):

The term "recursion" does not apply here.  Literally, it means "invoke/call (curse) again (re-)".  In software terms, this is to invoke a function while an earlier invocation is still active.  Each call requires pushing another call block on the run-time stack: return address, saved registers, arguments, etc.

Your code names an attribute of an object.  I can see your confusion: you *are* repeating the name.  However, the parser has no problem resolving this statically: it looks up the offset of the attribute within the object and includes that offset computation in finding the attribute value you want.  This is more of a repeated sum than stacked blocks.  Your self-referential structure is not **recursion**.